# WorkFront / AtTask API querying secondary objects

Tags: api, attask, workfront-api

I'm using the WorkFront / AtTask API and when looking up Tasks, I'd like to filter them down to the Projects that contain specific Roles.

using `/TASK/search/?fields=project:roles` it will show me the Roles, but then I'm not sure how to filter on those.

- **Accessing a tertiary object directly (fails)**

I tried `/TASK/search/?project:roles:ID=aaaaaaa` but the API returns (422) Unprocessable Entity.

- **Access from the parent object (works)**

task -> project -> `/PROJ/search/?roles:ID=aaaaaaa` works, but involves sub-queries to the API that are costly and slow.

- **Access from secondary object's ID fields (works)**

`/TASK/search/?project:ownerID=bbbbbbb` since it references a field of a secondary object and not yet another object. But I've only been able to make this work with single-instance references and don't know how to access the ID fields of collections without referencing them as objects.

---

So how could I filter or access down to a secondary object's collection? I can view them in a single API query, but can't seem to filter.

Task  >  It's Project  >  filter by Role

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is not available in Workfront, neither through the API nor through built-in tools like Reports. This is due to a constraint on the database side of things. After seeing this question I spoke with my enterprise support team at Workfront and received confirmation of this from the DBAs.

The solution that you provided is the best you can do - split this query into the front and back half of your parameters and filter results within your code.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I can think of thus far is:

1. Pull the list of acceptable projects based on role.

   - `/PROJ/search/?roles:ID=aaaaaa&...`
2. Save the list of projects in memory
3. Pull the list of Tasks in question

   - `/TASK/search/?...`
4. Remove the tasks that don't have a project ID from step 2

This way it's only 2 queries and the project query should have a minimal impact in terms of size and number of entries.